# euclidean distance finding using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have 5 coloums 1000+ rows csv file. I found the mean value. However, I need your help to apply euclidean distance algorithm and fill the Missing value. Kindly help me, folks.

```
# Importing libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

# Read csv file into a pandas dataframe

df = pd.read_csv(".\SampleData.csv", na_values = missing_values)
print (df)

#Fill the mean value on missing cells

df.fillna(df.mean())

#Fill the Mean value based on Class - Task2
print("Missing fields filled based on Class Value")
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('Class').transform('mean'))
print(df)
```

I completed finding the mean value to fill the Missing values

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: ````{'Country': 'USA', 'Age': '52', 'Sal': '12345', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'UK', 'Age': '23', 'Sal': '1142', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '4456', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '4456', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '?', 'Sal': '2345', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '3342', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '3452', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '?', 'Sal': '3562', 'OnWork': 'No'}````

Comment: It's not clear from your data or your question what exactly you are trying to do and how. For example, when you fill the data with the mean value, mean of what? When you fill the data by applying the Euclidean distance algorithm, on what data points? Please produce a minimum reproducible problem for us to solve. Edit your question to include sample data in the code, ensure your code runs without an issue and add notes to clarify your intentions. This will help clarify what you need help with and make it easier for people to help.